# Converting String of a tuple to a Tuple

Tags: python, arrays, string, list, tuples

If I have a string that looks like a tuple how can I make it into a tuple?

```
s = '(((3,),(4,2),(2,)),((1,),(2,4),(2,)))'
```

and I want to make it into a tuple that contains other tuples.

```
t = tuple((((3,),(4,2),(2,)),((1,),(2,4),(2,))))
```

Doesn't work because it makes even the `(` as a item in the tuple.

Comment: Please [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234) an answer if you think it solves your problem. It will community at large to recognize the correct solution. This can be done by clicking the green check mark next to the answer. See this [image](http://i.stack.imgur.com/uqJeW.png) for reference. Cheers.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to use [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval):

```
from ast import literal_eval
s = '(((3,),(4,2),(2,)),((1,),(2,4),(2,)))'

t = literal_eval(s)
print(t)
print(type(t))
(((3,), (4, 2), (2,)), ((1,), (2, 4), (2,)))
<class 'tuple'>
```